# i want to show file dialog to select file on windows from web application running on amazon linux2

Tags: python, linux, windows, user-interface, openfiledialog

I am using python and I want to open a save file dialog on local machine from the web application running on my amazon Linux instance. I tried using Tkinter but its seems very hard to get it done with it. how can it be done?

it would be helpful if the solution is applicable for production server.

Comment: You cannot use tkinter on a web server (without a large amount of work and some specialized knowledge).

Comment: thanks, please let me know if you have any idea on where should I look for any alternatives.

Comment: explain what actually you are trying to do and why you want to do it like that

Comment: I have a flask app running on ec2 Linux and I need to upload and download the csv file which I need to select from users machine. I tried xming with x11 forwarding but its not efficient enough for me. I am looking out for alternative for Tkinter here. any idea?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you need javascript for this. the file dialog is created by the browser running the javascript. If you google for `javascript upload file dialog` there's a ton of results...

Comment: if you need to download from amazon to local machine, there's the `send_file()` function in the Flask package... The browser takes care of the download itself